# AWS Opsworks app deploy not updating

Tags: amazon-web-services, opsworks

I have an app deployed, and then modify a deploy recipe to make a folder writable, but nothing changes when I deploy the app again. Do the chef recipes get cached? Do I have to boot a new instance every time my chef recipe changes in the deploy cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your custom cookbooks, you need to update the cookbooks on each instance. You can do this under the "Deployments" area by clicking "Run Command", selecting "Update Custom Cookbooks" from the drop-down and then pressing the "Update Custom Cookbooks" button. You can usually leave all instances checked, unless you don't want to update one for some reason.